# Integral of $-4\sin(2t - (pi/2)) $ weird behavior on wolfram alpha

Tags: trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, wolfram-alpha

I'm confused by what Wolfram Alpha is doing with my function:
$$-4\sin{(2t - (\pi/2))}$$
on why the it gets replaced by 
$$4\cos{(2t)}$$.

Is it equal? Link: [See behavior here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20-4sin(2t-(pi%2F2)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Using the angle-addition formula,
$$ \sin{(2t-\pi/2)} = \sin{2t}\cos{(\pi/2)}-\cos{2t}\sin{(\pi/2)} = -\cos{2t}. $$

Answer (score 3):

Yes, through two identities:

$$-4\sin(2t-\pi/2)=-4\sin(-(\pi/2-2t)) \\
=4\sin(\pi/2-2t) \\
=4\cos(2t).$$

The first identity is in the second equation, and is the fact that $\sin$ is odd. The second one is in the third equation, and is the basic cofunction identity (easily seen by drawing a right triangle).